# New line for all strings added to one

Tags: powershell, formatting, output, newline, carriage-return

How can I add all string to one variable with each in new line 
I have tried all these options but nothing seems to be working 
*All variable types here are string so thats not the problem

```
$Body = $alerts[1].description("'n") + $alerts[1].name("'n") + alerts[1].timeadded

$Body = $alerts[1].description "`n" + $alerts[1].name "`n" + $alerts[1].timeadded

$Body = $alerts[1].description `n + $alerts[1].name `n + $alerts[1].timeadded

$Body = $alerts[1].description `n  $alerts[1].name `n $alerts[1].timeadded
```

I want the output of `$body` to appear in new line each:

```
$alerts[1].description
$alerts[1].name
$alerts[1].timeadded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
$Body = $alerts[1].description + "`n" + $alerts[1].name + "`n" + $alerts[1].timeadded
```

The character `n corresponds to a newline, which should join the strings as you described.

Comment: This doesnt seems to be working to make it simple try running this :
$a = "AAA"
$b = "BBB"
$c = "CCC"
$newline  = $a + "\n" + $b + "\n" $c

Comment: @Fenomatik Check the updated answer as that was corrected.

Answer (score 1):

When making multiline strings where formatting is important you can always use a [here string](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx) and/or the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx).

```
$Body = @"
$($alerts[1].description)
$($alerts[1].name)
$($alerts[1].timeadded)
"@
```

Or

```
$Body = @"
{0}
{1}
{2}
"@ -f $alerts[1].description, $alerts[1].name, $alerts[1].timeadded
```

Or

```
$Body = "{0}`r`n{1}`r`n{2}" -f $alerts[1].description, $alerts[1].name, $alerts[1].timeadded
```

The features of both those approaches is more apparent when you start adding more information.

```
$Body = @"
The alert is described as: {0}
It has a name of {1}
This happened at {2} local time.
"@ -f $alerts[1].description, $alerts[1].name, $alerts[1].timeadded
```